# rsync --exclude issue when using bash variable

Tags: bash, variables, rsync, filter-run-excluding

I need to copy a source directory to under a destination directory with rsync in bash, with excluding files having specific extensions (.qcow2). It works properly when I try typing the command manually, however fails when using with bash variable.

I set a bash variable, on below is its content:

```
# echo $line
/mnt/source --exclude='*.qcow2'
```

Although there is the exclude parameter, rsync is copying the ".qcow2" file:

```
# rsync -av $line destination/
sending incremental file list
source/Atlas/
source/Atlas/atlas.sh
source/Atlas/atlas.qcow2

sent 2143238309 bytes  received 56 bytes  115850722.43 bytes/sec
total size is 2143164594  speedup is 1.00
```

Meanwhile rsync is running I can see the process as below:

```
# ps -ef | grep rsync
root     39058 11032 62 14:56 pts/22   00:00:01 rsync -av /mnt/source --exclude='*.qcow2' destination/
root     39059 39058  0 14:56 pts/22   00:00:00 rsync -av /mnt/source --exclude='*.qcow2' destination/
root     39060 39059 71 14:56 pts/22   00:00:02 rsync -av /mnt/source --exclude='*.qcow2' destination/
root     39066 14866  0 14:56 pts/24   00:00:00 grep rsync
```

".qcow2" file is copied above, this is what I want to avoid.

When I run the same command without the variable, as seen on the ps output (after removing the files on the destination directory), it works properly, ".qcow2" file is not transferred:

```
# rm -f destination/Atlas/*
# rsync -av /mnt/source --exclude='*.qcow2' destination/
sending incremental file list
source/Atlas/
source/Atlas/atlas.sh

sent 14956 bytes  received 37 bytes  29986.00 bytes/sec
total size is 202930  speedup is 13.53
```

How can I make it work, to avoid ".qcow2" file transfer, with using variables in bash?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's another duplicate question over on superuser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527983/why-do-bash-parameter-expansions-cause-an-rsync-command-to-operate-differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoting in your variable is off. Try this:

```
$ line='/mnt/source --exclude=*.qcow2'
$ echo $line
/mnt/source --exclude=*.qcow2
$ rsync -av $line destination/
```

Comment: @JimRaynor There are some situations where the unquoted wildcard character (`*`) will cause trouble. See the duplicate questions for better ways to do it (hint: use an array).