# How to quote arguments with space in a variable inside another variable?

Tags: bash, quotes

I have a script where I need to calculate complicated arguments and they could contain spaces. I need to store arguments in variable `var1` and this variable and other arguments inside variable `var2`. I pass `var2` as arguments to another script.

Example:

```
$ var1="2 3 4"
$ var2="1 \"$var1\" 5"
$ ./sript.sh $var2
```

Now "2 3 4" is not one argument to the script, but 3 ones: `"2`, `3` and `4"`. What I need is what happens if I call `./sript.sh 1 "2 3 4" 5`, but with variable inside variable...

I tried with all mask and quote tricks I know, but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't; you use an array.

```
$ var1="2 3 4"
$ var2=(1 "$var1" 5)
$ ./script.sh "${var2[@]}"
```

Comment: I thought about that. Is that really the only way? I fear other script developer don't understand arrays in bash scripts...

Comment: Yes, that's the only way. Learn them up.

Comment: @jan See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432352/list-of-arguments-in-only-one-variable-in-bash), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527983/why-do-bash-parameter-expansions-cause-an-rsync-command-to-operate-differently), and  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261331/backup-script-fails-with-the-rsync-commands-options-in-a-quoted-variable/261407#261407) for examples of using arrays to store parameters and options.