# Variable in command substitution is expanded into multiple arguments

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution

I have tried to create a method in a bash script which should be able to perform a curl operation with a variable number of headers, however I seem to get stuck in that the curl command consider the header arguments to be multiple arguments as they contain spaces.

When I run the following line in bash I get a 201 response:

```
response=$($executable -X POST localhost:9200/index-template/globalmetadata --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null --verbose --data "@${full_path}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" )
```

If I run the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

submit_request () {
  full_path=/home/mat/globalmetadata.json

  header_option=""
  header_options=""
  for header in "${@:1}"; do # looping over the  elements of the $@ array ($1, $2...)
    header_option=$(printf " -H %s" "$header")
    header_options=$(printf '%s%s' "$header_options" "$header_option")
  done

  echo Headers: $header_options

  executable=curl

  #response=$($executable -X POST localhost:9200/index-template/globalmetadata --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null --verbose --data "@${full_path}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" )
  response=$($executable -X POST localhost:9200/index-template/globalmetadata --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null --verbose --data "@${full_path}" $header_option )

  echo $response

}

submit_request "\"Content-Type: application/json\""
```

I get this output:

```
Headers: -H "Content-Type: application/json"
======= 3
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:9200...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9200 (#0)
> POST /index-template/globalmetadata HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9200
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 3232
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [3232 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
< X-elastic-product: Elasticsearch
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 97
< 
{ [97 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Could not resolve host: application
* Closing connection 1
406000
```

What I have noticed is that even though the headers are `-H "Content-Type: application/json`, curl says `Could not resolve host: application`. I suspect that it splits the arguments into two due to space between `Content-Type:` and `application/json`.

I tried to mix and match quotes and double quotes in all kinds of combination but nothing really worked.

Comment: Replace in your `curl` command `$header_option` with `"$header_option"`?

Comment: Storing lists of arguments as plain strings only works for very simple cases; for something like this, you need to use an array, with each argument stored as a separate array element (and correct quoting when you expand the array). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527983/why-do-bash-parameter-expansions-cause-an-rsync-command-to-operate-differently) and [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GordonDavisson is right, you'll have to put your `header_options` in an array. <s>Just be aware that using the array `"${header_options[@]}"` when it is empty will result in an empty argument in your `curl` command, but You can get rid of this problem by storing the whole command in an other array.</s>

```sh
submit_request () {

    local -a header_options
    for arg; do header_options+=(-H "$arg"); done

    local -a curl_command=( \
        curl \
        -X POST \
        localhost:9200/index-template/globalmetadata \
        --write-out '%{http_code}' \
        --silent \
        --output /dev/null \
        --verbose \
        --data '@/home/mat/globalmetadata.json' \
        "${header_options[@]}" \
    )

    local response=$( "${curl_command[@]}" )

    printf '%s\n' "$response"
}
```

Comment: I don't think the precaution around an empty `header_options` array is necessary. Empty arrays expand to nothing.

Comment: You're right, I was mislead by my testing of arguments with `printf '%q\n' "$@"`...